Pending Verification Status for OAuth Consent Screen
I am reaching out regarding an issue I'm experiencing with the verification status of my app on the Google Cloud Console OAuth consent screen. Despite completing the domain verification process in Google Search Console, the verification status remains pending.
I kindly request your assistance in resolving this issue promptly to ensure the smooth operation of our app. Please check the image.OAuth Consent Screen

You should have received a mail with instructions of the next steps. It was sent to the mail used to create the consent screen. There's not much we can do here
